# Adding an additional printf line affects C code

Tags: c, execution

I am adding a simple printf line in a code and it affects whether the line before will be executed or not. I restarted the terminal but it's still the same. I tried it on an online compiler and executor and there's no problem, but in my computer I have this problem. Restarting the PC doesn't help.

```
else
    {
        lf++;
    }
```

when I put this lf is not increased and the program outputs "0 strings" on my PC, "4 strings" on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php

When I replace it with

```
else
    {
        lf++;
        printf("\ndo we even get here?\n");
    }
```

it outputs "4 strings" in both platforms (as it should).
What can be the reason behind this? As far as I know a simple printf shouldn't affect whether the line before will be executed or not, independent from which C compiler I use.

Here is the original code:

```
#include"mylib.h"
#define MAX 67108863
char tab[100][27];
double val[100];
int l;

void showtab(FILE *fout)
{
    int i, j;
    printf("\nnumber of strings is %d\n",l);
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        fprintf(fout,"%lf ",val[i]);
        for(j=0;j<26;j++)
        {
            if(tab[i][j])
                fputc('a'+j,fout);          
        }
        fprintf(fout,"\n");
    }
}

int find(char*s, int stl)
{
    int i, j, b=1;
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        if(tab[i][26]!=stl)
            continue;
        for(j=0;j<stl;j++)
        {
            if(tab[i][s[j]-'a']!=1)
            {
                b=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(b==0)
        {
            b=1;
            continue;
        }
        return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

void clean()
{
    int i, j, k, lf=0;
    for(i=0;i<l-1 && j<l;i++)
    {
        if(j<=i)
            j=i+1;
        if(val[i]==0)
        {
            while(j<l)
            {
                if(val[j]!=0)
                {
                    for(k=0;k<27;k++)
                        tab[i][k]=tab[j][k];
                    val[i]=val[j];
                    val[j]=0;
                    j++;
                    lf++;
                    break;
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lf++;
        }
    }
    l=lf;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    char s[26], b=1, inequ;
    int adr, stl, i;
    double v;
    FILE* fin=fopen("data","r");
    FILE* fout=fopen("canonical.form","w");
    l=0;
    while(b)
    {
        fscanf(fin,"%s",s);
        if(s[0]!='<' && s[0]!='>')
        {
            fscanf(fin,"%lf",&v);
            stl=strlen(s);
            adr=find(s,stl);
            if(adr==-1)
            {
                for(i=0;i<26;i++)
                    tab[l][i]=0;
                for(i=0;i<stl;i++)
                    tab[l][s[i]-'a']=1;
                tab[l][26]=stl;
                val[l]=v;
                l++;
            }
            else
                val[adr]+=v;
        }
        else
        {
            if(s[0]=='<')
                inequ=-1;
            else
                inequ=1;
            b=0;
        }
    }
    while(fscanf(fin,"%s %lf",s,&v)==2)
    {
        stl=strlen(s);
        adr=find(s,stl);
        if(adr==-1)
        {
            for(i=0;i<26;i++)
                tab[l][i]=0;
            for(i=0;i<stl;i++)
                tab[l][s[i]-'a']=1;
            val[l]=-v;
            l++;
        }
        else
            val[adr]-=v;
    }
    clean();
    if(inequ==-1)
        fprintf(fout,"0>=\n");
    else
        fprintf(fout,"0<=\n");
    showtab(fout); 
    return 0;
}
```

I don't use anything I defined in mylib.h in this piece of code except

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
```

and here is the input file:

```
az 1.000000
z -1.000000
bz 1.000000
z -1.000000
abz -1.000000
z 1.000000
ab 1.000000
z 1.000000
abz -1.000000
a -1.000000
b -1.000000
ab 1.000000
<=
ab 1.000000
b -1.000000
zb 1.000000
b -1.000000
azb -1.000000
b 1.000000
ba 1.000000
a -1.000000
za 1.000000
a -1.000000
bza -1.000000
a 1.000000
xyab 3.000000
ab -3.000000
zab 3.000000
ab -3.000000
xyzab -3.000000
ab 3.000000
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Compile with **ALL WARNINGS** enabled and mind the warnings (`gcc -Wall -Wextra ...` or `clang -Weverything ...`).

Comment: Sounds like UB. Can't be sure. Paste more code.

Comment: I've compiled with -Wall -Wextra, no warning. @pmg

Comment: It is not 'printf("\ndo we even get here?\n");' which outputs the number of strings, it just affects in an irrational manner the execution of the line before. @2501

Comment: This is some serious spaghetti code. Once you get this working, I would strongly recommend to post the working code at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

You don't initialize your variables before using them so you invoke undefined behavior.

You need to set `j`, `k` etc to zero.

Comment: There is also a dire lack of error checking, and no checks for going beyond the bounds of arrays, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I just initialized j in the function clean and it works now.